# How to create object in excel by javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

i wonder how to create shape object by javasript in excel. i know how to read js code in vba but have no idea how get handles to objects. below working addition example.

```
Public Sub TestJS()
    Dim script As New ScriptControl
    Dim result As Variant
    script.Language = "JScript"
    With script
        .AddCode "function add(a,b) {return 'result from '+a+' + '+b+' is ' +(a+b);}"
        result = .Run("add", 1, 2)
    End With
    
    Cells(1, 1) = result
End Sub
```

finally i try to run this code fragment in excel.
js files and full code [here](https://github.com/bkuzmic/pdf417-js)

```
        PDF417.init(hub3_code);             

        var barcode = PDF417.getBarcodeArray();

        // block sizes (width and height) in pixels
        var bw = 2;
        var bh = 2;

        // create canvas element based on number of columns and rows in barcode
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = bw * barcode['num_cols'];
        canvas.height = bh * barcode['num_rows'];
        document.getElementById('barcode').appendChild(canvas);

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

any advice are welcome

Comment: A script control is not the same as a browser javascript host - it doesn't have window/document etc etc.

Comment: so its imposible to create object with script cotroll? maybe json for vba can do that?

Comment: You could try using a WebBrowser control in a form or on a worksheet - that would give you a browser host.  I've not looked the scripts you're using so I'm not sure if they're compatible with IE (which is sort of what you get with the WebBrowser  control)